# Is rebuilding the clutch any good?

Tags: toyota, clutch, corolla

Is rebuilding the clutch any good, or should I have it replaced?

If it's convenient to have it rebuilt (in terms of cost vs. 
 benefit),  is there anything I need to keep an eye on or fix/replace along with the clutch (in an online post I saw they talked about making sure they replace the springs, pilot bearing, throw-out bearing and have the flywheel resurfaced).

Thanks in advance

P. S.  If it makes a difference the car in question is a Toyota Corolla 2009

Post I read: http://www.binderplanet.com/forums/index.php?threads/clutch-rebuilt-vs-new.129803/

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

For a modern car like that I'd go for a new one - I'd only look at rebuild clutches for older cars where decent quality new clutches aren't available. As Mike says, the biggest aspect of changing a clutch is the labour involved in doing the change, the actual cost of the parts is small in comparison - so always go for the best quality parts you can get, to avoid having to do it again!

Answer (score 1):

In the past, a re-built clutch had new leather friction material riveted to the clutch centre plate, which then had to be bedded in...

So, now I would fit a new centre plate, thrust bearing, pressure plate and pilot bearing... The flywheel may or may not need to be dressed...

Given the work necessary to get to some clutches, it is best to make sure you only do the job once...